# Xcode 6.1 Error bound value in a conditional binding must be Optional type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My current swift code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

if let textLabel = cell.textLabel {
  textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  textLabel.highlightedTextColor = textLabel.textColor
}
```

is getting error: "bound value in a conditional binding must be Optional type" on the 3 line:

```
   if let textLabel = cell.textLabel {
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.textLabel` keeps changing its optional status with each release of Xcode, which is highly irritating. Check to see how it's defined in the version you're using, you may not need the optional binding.